# Is there a way to determine whether my test code is executed in ADO Pipeline (as opposed to dev machine)?

Tags: azure-devops

Yes, I know we should run the same on server as we run locally, but we have a test that fails in ADO but not locally and we know why. For now, I'd like to just disable the test on server but still run it locally.

We use xunit and I plan to make an attribute for it.

But how can the attrbute detect if it's running 'in the cloud' as opposed to running on our dev machines?

Comment: How do you run the test in Azure Pipeline? Can you share some details about the Azure Pipeline?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT: Quite standard, I'd say:

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

Comment: You can consider using the test category in your test. Then we can filter the test based on the test category in Vstest task. Please refer to my answer and check if it can give you some help

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you need to run the related test on local server and skip it when using Azure DevOps pipeline.

To meet your requirement, you can consider adding **test category** to the test method in your xUnit test. Then you can exclude the target test in the VStest task.

For example:

```
[Fact]
[Trait("Category", "Integration")]
public async Task FooTest()
```

Vstest task: `testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=!Integration'`

```
steps:
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=!Integration'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

In this case, the test method with the related category will be exclude when running the test in Azure Pipeline.

On your local machine, all tests will be executed if there is no any filters.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Vstest task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for chipping in -- it does however not answer my question about how it can be detected whether I'm running test from a build agent. I know about Categories and preferred the other approach.

Comment: @AndersJuul When you executing the test on build agent and local machine, they will execute the similar test command. Therefore we cannot directly judge. When using test category, you can add the test filter in Build Pipeline to tell the test is running on build agent. it will exclude the related tests. When you running the test on local machine, you don't need to add filter. This means that all tests will run on local machine